# What is this number square puzzle called? (10x10 grid with numbers 1-100)

Tags: puzzle-identification, board-games, pencil-and-paper-games

Does anyone happen to know a name for this traditional(?) number square puzzle/game?

The puzzle has a board of 10x10 squares that are initially empty. The player starts the game by entering the number `1` in a single square of their choice. After that they start "moving" around the board, jumping from the last square to the next following a couple of rules:

- One can move 3 squares horizontally or vertically, or 2 diagonally
- One cannot move to a square that is already occupied by a number
- One must (of course) stay in bounds of the board all the time

On each move, the number entered in the target square increases by one. The goal is to finish with the board completely filled with numbers from 1 to 100.

For example, here are the possible moves after inserting the first number:

[image: Move choices after starting the game]

And if the player chooses to move diagonally right and upwards (NE), the board and possible next moves look like this:

[image: Move choices after the next move]

Traditionally this puzzle/game has been played on pen and paper. I know people who say they've played this at least as early as in the 1990's but I haven't been able to find any history of the game online — most likely because I don't know its name (if it even has one) and have thus not searched with the right search terms.

Does anyone happen to know the name of this puzzle/game? I would also love to know when and where this originated and who invented this but I understand that might be impossible to find out.

I've only found one [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-fully-fill-a-10-by-10-grid-with-numbers-from-1-to-100-in-succession-starting-at-any-square-with-number-1-and-knowing-that-you-can-add-the-next-number-only-3-squares-away-horizontally-or-vertically-or-2) talking about the same puzzle but that also lacked a name for it.

Comment: So it's a kind of [knight's tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) problem, but using a type of piece different from a knight. I don't know what a piece with these moves is called though.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, yes, I've heard that comparison done before. And now that I think of it, this might actually be a derivative of that classic puzzle which could make this centuries old also. And even though I knew about knight's tour before, following your Wikipedia link made me read a bit about [Hamiltonian path problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) in general, and if this is indeed one, I've already found a fitting umbrella term for such puzzles in general now. Thank you!

Comment: Looked it up, found Newt under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_chess_piece#N

Comment: Thanks @EdMurphy! I don't think anyone has ever called it "newt's tour" but that might be a fitting name if one doesn't exist. :-D

Comment: On Rosetta Code, they are calling it a Hopido: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Solve_a_Hopido_puzzle

Comment: Thanks! If I understood correctly, Hopidos only use some of the square grid as allowed cells to move into, but perhaps it's also a valid Hopido to allow movement into all of the cells, i.e. a "blank" square. Anyway, that's an interesting find!